# Parse JSON using Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a JSON object that's written in a weird way.

```
> {"custom": [ { "name": "addressIdNum", "valueNum": 12345678},  {
> "name": "cancelledDateAt", "valueAt": "2017-02-30T01:43:04.000Z" }] }
```

Not sure how to parse something like this. The keys are addressIdNum and cancelledDateAt and the values  are 12345678 and 2017-02-30T01:43:04.000Z respectively.

How do I parse this using Snowflake SQL?

Thanks for all your help!

Best,
Preet Rajdeo

Answer (score 3):

If your input is ALWAYS in this form (two elements in an array, with the same fields in the same element), you can combine [PARSE_JSON](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html) function and the [path access](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#traversing-semi-structured-data).

Just try this:

```
with input as (
  select parse_json(
    '{"custom": [ { "name": "addressIdNum", "valueNum": 12345678},  {"name": "cancelledDateAt", "valueAt": "2017-02-30T01:43:04.000Z" }] }') 
  as json) 
select json:custom[0].valueNum::integer, json:custom[1].valueAt::timestamp from input;
----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
 JSON:CUSTOM[0].VALUENUM::INTEGER | JSON:CUSTOM[1].VALUEAT::TIMESTAMP |
----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
 12345678                         | 2017-03-01 17:43:04               |
----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

However, if the structure of your data might be different (e.g. elements in the array might be in a different order), it's probably best to write a JavaScript UDF in Snowflake to convert such messy data into something easier.

Comment: How do you write a Javascript UDF?

Comment: Did you look in the manual? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js.html